# ¿Cómo deshabilitar el autocompletado de un edittext?

Tags: android, android-studio, edittext

Tengo un EditText que específicamente esta configurado para solo aceptar 5 caracteres y que sean solo caracteres alfanuméricos. Estoy probando con un dispositivo móvil Xiamoi, y a este campo mencionado le aparece la sugerencia de autocompletado de numero de tarjeta (que proviene de la app propia del móvil que administra los datos bancarios del usuario) y es claro que el campo no esta configurado para aceptar un dato de tal tipo y tal longitud.

Ya intente desactivar esa sugerencia de autocompletado agregando al inputype del edittext la bandera:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Pero aun así no deshabilita el autocompletado.

¿Saben si existe otra manera de no mostrar el autocompletado?

Como dato, se me ocurre pensar que parte de la IA de Xiaomi esta relacionando el nombre del campo (Se llama "Numero de cajero", y la vista tal cual lleva un titulo de "Cajero automático") al tipo de dato y por eso esta mostrando tal sugerencia aunque lo haya deshabilitado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar:

```
android:importantForAutofill="no"
```

> Esto deshabilitaría el "autocomplete", ya que el valor **"no"**, indica:
>   Esta vista no es importante para el autocompletado.

Revisa la documentación:

[**Cómo optimizar tu app para el autocompletado**](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill-optimize)